# Moment.JS using timezone

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, timezone, momentjs

I'm using momemt.js and moment-timezone.js to output time in the browser. Now I'm working with epoch time sent from the server this epoch has been converted to central. Now I want to display the time in EST/EDT. I have `moment().tz("America/New_York").format();` and `moment.unix(val.departure_time).format("h:mm a");` to format my time. The problem is that the times in the client are in central  (1 hour behind eastern time). What am I doing wrong?

I'm not very familiar when working with dates so please be gentle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `moment()` - that is getting the *current* time.  You don't appear to be assigning it to anything.

It's hard to tell from the wording of your question, but I assume `val.departure_time` is the Unix Epoch-based time, as an integer number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970 UTC.  If so, you probably want to do this:

```
moment.unix(val.departure_time).tz("America/New_York").format("h:mm a")
```